# Is it possible to have a link between a 10GbE NIC and 1GbE Switch with a SFP+ DAC?

Tags: networking, nic, 10gbethernet, sfp

I've just installed an Intel 82599 based NIC with 2 SFP+ ports in my server. Right now I have a PowerConnect 2824 switch, which has 2 1Gb SFP ports.

I tried linking them with a 10Gb SFP+ DAC (a 10gtek, bought as compatible with Dell), but there was no way I could make it work. The Switch always showed the port as down, and so did the card.

I was not able to change the speed in the Card to make it 1Gb, so I guess the cable is only good for 10Gb, although in the specs it says it handles 1-10Gb.

This is only temporary: we are waiting for a new switch (Dell X1052) that has 4 10Gb SFP+ ports, where I hope everything will work fine, but I was trying to setup the link already with the existing equipment if possible.

Comment: Since PowerConnect 2824 switch only suppoRT SFP ports, and the cable you have is a [10G SFP+ DAC](http://www.fs.com/c/generic-10g-sfp-dac-1115), it seems that SFP modules are not compatible the the cable. Maybe difficult to set up a connection that works.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a pair of *Copper SFP adapters* to connect things temporarily.

[image]

The cable you have likely isn't compatible. The PowerConnect 2824 doesn't have SFP+ ports (*only SFP*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already have the server connected and working with the switch using other NICs with RJ45 ports. The new NIC is to be used when the new switch arrives (still some weeks on the future). Just trying to confirm if the problem is the cable/compatibility, as it seems so.

Comment: The difference between SFP and SFP+ is key here.  The two standards seem like they should be backwards compatible... but upon some minor research, that doesn't appear to be the case.  CMIW.

Comment: AIUI you can usually use a SFP transciver in a SFP+ slot but you can't use a SFP+ transiciver (or direct attach cable) in a SFP slot.